# Tcl-C - can't require specific package when running Tcl Interperter from C

Tags: c, tcl

I want to extend my C/C++ application with Tcl.
I wrote the following code that should create Tcl Interpreter but I want it to load user package that is located in ./user/tcl8.6.6/lib .

The problem is that my program exists without loading anything.
So after I Debug the program I saw that the result in the interpreter after running the line that should require my package is: `*myinterp = {result = 0x647d58 "can't find package user", freeProc = 0x0, errorLine = 1}`

I assume that the Tcl Interperter that is invoked by this line is located somewhere that doesn't have this package under it's lib subfolder.

So my question is how can I see what is the path to the shell that is invoked (maybe it is something related to TCL_LIBRARY or other environment variables?) and how can I update it or add to it the location to the folder contains my user package from my C code??

This is the code I wrote:

```
int main() {
    Tcl_Interp *myinterp;
    int status;

    printf ("Your Program will run ... \n");
    myinterp = Tcl_CreateInterp();

    std::string test = "package require user";
    status = Tcl_Eval(myinterp,test.c_str());

    std::string test = "set a 5";
    status = Tcl_Eval(myinterp,test.c_str());

    printf ("Your Program has completed\n");
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Add the relevant directory to the `auto_path` list: `lappend auto_path /path/to/package`

Comment: That's C++, not C, btw...

Comment: oops...My mistake
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tcl initialises where to load packages from from the `TCLLIBPATH` environment variable, which if defined must contain a Tcl list of directories to search for `pkgIndex.tcl` files (which define how to load the package implementations). However, within your application if you know where the library package is, you should instead append that location to the list in the `auto_path` global variable:

```
std::string libLocation = "/some/directory/I/know";
Tcl_SetVar(interp, "auto_path", libLocation.c_str(),
        TCL_GLOBAL_ONLY | TCL_APPEND_VALUE | TCL_LIST_ELEMENT);
```

Do that after creating the interpreter but before evaluating your script.

---

Don't set `TCL_LIBRARY` if you can avoid it. It defines where Tcl gets its *internal* library scripts from. I guess you might need to set it if you're embedding Tcl and aren't installing it separately, but that's not where non-built-in packages are to be found.

Comment: I have a strange problem.
my interpreter that I am loading has no tcl_library and no auto_path (before setting them) I think this is my problem but I don't know how to change it